# Label number in loop "for" in metapost

Tags: labels, metapost

I first create ten points p[1],..., p[10] in MetaPost. Afterward, I use the following loop:

```
for i = 1 upto 10:

   dotlabel.bot(btex i etex, p[i]);

endfor
```

then it creates in the pdf file 10 letters 'i' below 10 point p[i]. But I want ten numbers from 1 to 10 below ten points p[i].

I do not know how to do that. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please edit your post so that your example will be a MWE that can be compiled as it is: add the `\starttext` … `\stoptext` and the piece of code creating your points.

Comment: I will add a proper answer later, but have a look at sections 11.2.4 and 12.5 of [my notes on Drawing with Metapost](https://github.com/thruston/Drawing-with-Metapost/blob/master/Drawing-with-Metapost.pdf).

Comment: `decimal i` might be a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: @Thruston Your documents are undoubtedly wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: @mickep It works correctly and easily. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### About dynamic labels in Metapost

The `label` macro is defined, in `plain.mp`, to take two arguments

1. a `string` or `picture` expression (but nothing else)
2. a `pair` expression

It will draw the string or picture neatly at the point
defined by the pair expression.  So you can do

```
label("Hello", origin);
```

to get "Hello" centered on the point `(0, 0)`.

The way this works is (simplified):

```
vardef label(expr s,z) =
  save p; picture p;
  p = s if string s: infont defaultfont fi;
  ... positioning code ...
enddef;
```

So that, if the first argument `s` is a string, then
the macro turns it into a picture `p` first.

So the question is, how do I generate a string or a picture dynamically in a loop?

### Simple labels in the default font

The simplest way to turn a numeric variable into a string is to use `decimal`

```
for i = 1 upto 10:
    label(decimal i, (20i, 0));
endfor
```

or perhaps you want them in a particular font other than the default.

```
for i = 1 upto 10:
    label(decimal i infont "phvr8r", (20i, 0));
endfor
```

Now you are sending a `picture` to label each time.

### Dynamic labels using TeX

You can't generate dynamic labels directly using `btex ... etex`.  This is
because `btex` and `etex` act like a special pair of quote marks that turn
a list of tokens into a `picture` variable, but MP does not expand any of the tokens inside `btex ... etex` before processing them with TeX. So if you try this

```
for i = 1 upto 10:
    label(btex i etex, (20i, 0));
endfor
```

You get no errors but each label is an "i".   To get round this, you can use the `TEX` macro.

```
input TEX
for i = 1 upto 10:
    label(TEX(decimal i), (20i, 0));
endfor
```

the `TEX` macro takes a regular `string` and passes it out to TeX and then returns the resulting `picture`. This means you can do things like

```
input TEX
for i = 1 upto 10:
    label(TEX("$p_{" & decimal i & "}$"), (20i, 0));
endfor
```

because MP will expand the tokens before it passes them to the `TEX` macro.  In this case there are three strings to concatenate.

### Faster dynamic labels with TeX

The only problem with the TEX macro is that it is very slow.  Because it writes each label out to a temporary file.
At the cost of some low level fiddling with `write` you can speed it up like this.

```
for i = 1 upto 10:
    write "label(btex $p_{" & decimal i & "}$ etex, (" & decimal 20i & ",0));" to ".mplabels";
endfor
write EOF to ".mplabels";
input ".mplabels";
```

What this does is write ten lines to a temporary local file:

```
label(btex $p_{1}$ etex, (20, 0));
label(btex $p_{2}$ etex, (40, 0));
label(btex $p_{3}$ etex, (60, 0));
... etc ...
```

and then read them all back in and process them in one go.

### Modern, fast dynamic labels

But actually you don't need to do any of that any more.  Instead you should be using
`lualatex` and `luamplib` instead.  Use a template like this, and process it with
`lualatex` instead of `mpost`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}  % <--- this is important
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Then you can do your dynamic labels at high speed like this

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    for i = 1 upto 10:
        label("$p_{" & decimal i & "}$", (20i, 0));
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

which produces this (when compiled with `lualatex`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If one wants to stick to MetaPost without Lua(La)Tex, there is also the `latexmp`MetaPost package which has its own `textext` macro, and a `textextlabel=enable` option. The only caveat is that a double compilation is needed to produce and include the labels. Slower than LuaLaTeX, but much quicker than the TEX macro.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is connected to using `btex etex`. This answer will work:

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
path p[];
for i = 1 upto 10:
   p[i]:= (10i,0);
   dotlabel.bot(i, p[i]);
endfor
%variables

\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

BTW, please give us a fully compilable MWE, it will increase your chances of getting any answers, since we won't have to do any additional work.

Comment: Note that this works in Context because the Metafun version of the `label` macro is a bit smarter than the macro in plain MP.  In plain MP you will get a "Not implemented" error if you pass a `numeric` to `label` (or `dotlabel), but the Metafun version will automatically convert a numeric into a string and then into a picture to be drawn.